# Make sql where statement dynamic for each value from string_split

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, where-in

I'm currently searching a table with a relative static query. 
This is not a perfect query, because the original search input in this example is `Denny drive`. The search input should be splitted by spaces (maybe with `string_split`). As a result I've only want the rows, where `denny` and `drive` is in `givenname`, `surename` or `streetaddress`.

That is the current query for zwei therms:

```sql
DECLARE @query1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @query2 NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @query1='Denny'
SET @query2='drive'

SELECT
    *
FROM
    fakenames f
WHERE
    (givenname like '%' + @query1 + '%' OR surname like '%' + @query1 + '%' OR streetaddress like '%' + @query1 + '%') AND 
    (givenname like '%' + @query2 + '%' OR surname like '%' + @query2 + '%' OR streetaddress like '%' + @query2 + '%')
```

Is it possible to make the where statement more flexible? So that I can have only one variable with `SET @query='Denny drive vegas'` and for each splitted element the where statement is combined with one more `(givenname like '%' + @queryY + '%' OR surname like '%' + @queryY + '%' OR streetaddress like '%' + @queryY + '%')`

Sample data:

```
| givenname | surname  | streetaddress        |
|:----------|---------:|:--------------------:|
| Irene     | Williams | 2835 Crestview Manor |
| Denny     | Wade     | 885 Baker drive      |
| Denny     | Reese    | 129 Owagner Lane     |
```

Expected result:

```
| givenname | surname  | streetaddress        |
|:----------|---------:|:--------------------:|
| Denny     | Wade     | 885 Baker drive      |
```

Comment: _Both_ must be present in _at least one_ column?

Comment: Yes @SalmanA, each element from query must be present in at least one column.

Comment: @David  . . . Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: One hack could be to concat everything and use contains :-)

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've added sample data and expected result to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is flexible:

```
Table
Create Table fakenames
(
givenname nVarChar(25),
surname nVarChar(25),
streetaddress nVarChar(50)
)
Insert Into fakenames Values
('Denny','Smith','Main St'),
('Billy','vegas','Main St'),
('John','Travolta','Main St'),
('Mick','Jagger','Willow Ave'),
('Mary','Jane','Oak drive')
```

Query

```
Declare @query nVarChar(50) = 'Denny drive vegas'

;With cte As
(
SELECT
    f.*, 
    v1.value As val1,
    v2.value As val2,
    v3.value As val3
FROM
    fakenames f Left Join
    String_Split(@query,' ') v1 On f.givenname Like '%' + v1.value + '%' Left Join
    String_Split(@query,' ') v2 On f.surname Like '%' + v2.value + '%' Left Join
    String_Split(@query,' ') v3 On f.streetaddress Like '%' + v3.value + '%'
)
Select * From cte
WHERE
    val1 Is Not Null Or
    val2 Is Not Null Or
    val3 Is Not Null
```

Result

```
givenname   surname streetaddress   val1    val2    val3
---------   ------- -------------   ---     ---     ---
Denny       Smith   Main St         Denny   NULL    NULL
Billy       vegas   Main St         NULL    vegas   NULL
Mary        Jane    Oak drive       NULL    NULL    drive
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you may try with the next approach. You need to split your search text using `STRING_SPLIT()` (or other function if you don't use SQL Server 2016+) and count the matches for every part of splitted text.

Input:

```
CREATE TABLE #fakenames (
   givenname varchar(100),
   surname varchar(100),
   streetaddress varchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO #fakenames
   (givenname, surname, streetaddress)
VALUES
   ('Irene', 'Williams', '2835 Crestview Manor'),
   ('Denny', 'Wade',     '885 Baker drive'),
   ('Denny', 'Reese',    '129 Owagner Lane')
```

Statement:

```
DECLARE @query varchar(max)
SET @query = 'Denny drive'

SELECT f.*
FROM #fakenames f
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(@query, ' ') s
GROUP BY f.givenname, f.surname, f.streetaddress
HAVING 
   SUM(CASE 
       WHEN (givenname LIKE '%' + s.[value] + '%') OR 
            (surname LIKE '%' + s.[value] + '%') OR 
            (streetaddress LIKE '%' + s.[value] + '%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
   ) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@query, ' '))
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------
givenname   surname streetaddress
---------------------------------
Denny       Wade    885 Baker drive
```